# Jquery Show Input Text Field After Click Event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Wassup Folks,

I want, that if I click on the label for the switcher called "Private Session" that it reveals the hidden input to accept a user chosen password for a room in order to create a private session (using bootstrap btw).

"room.blade.php"

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://github.com/</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="...">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://jira.com/</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="...">
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Private Session?</label>
        </div>

        <br>
        <input type="text" id="hiddenInput" hidden>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Create Room</button>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Hide menu once we know its width
        $('#customSwitch1').click(function() {
            var $hiddenInput = $('.hiddenInput');
            if ($hiddenInput.is(':invisible')) {
                $hiddenInput.show();

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined hiddenInput as id but you are calling class

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        // Hide menu once we know its width
        $('#customSwitch1').click(function() {
            var $hiddenInput = $('#hiddenInput');
            if ($hiddenInput.is(':invisible')) {
                $hiddenInput.show();

            }
        });
    });
```